# dismissModalViewController = EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal UIView that is also a delegate so when it comes out it sends some variables back to my DetailViewController.
I know the proper way to dismiss the presented ModalViewController is to dismiss it from my DetailView (the one who presents the modal view).
The problem is if the modalview is a tableview it works fine but somehow this is not working.

```
-(void)pickDateControllerFinished:(PickDateController *)controller{
dateSelected = [controller.datePicker date];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

NSLog(@"DateSelected %@", dateSelected);
}
```

So the variable actually passes but the View just won't dismiss.
I'm using IOS5 with storyboard, no ARC.

I get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

I also tried using:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // no errors but this doesn't dismiss
```

Running out of options here...
Any sugestions ?

Comment: Run under the Zombies instrument.

Comment: On which line are you getting `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`?

Comment: I normally dismiss the modal view control from itself and not the presenting view controller. Give that a try as [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 2):

You should try

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```